# Tableau-Conditional_Formatting

Tags: tableau-api, conditional-formatting

I have conditionally formatted columns in Tableau. How do I apply the conditional formatting to the Totals and Grand Totals?

I used the individual measure colors on the marks card and then used the advanced button to allow me to select the number of steps to provide a gradient color to the measure totals